# Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Code: 4004 System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid, user-controls

I'm getting this error in a very strange manner. I've been able to isolate it, and I know what is causing it, but I don't have a clue why.

This is the situation: I have a ChildWindow, which contains a TabControl, which contains two UserControl, and both of them contain a datagrid like this causing the unhandled error:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="PersonEmailDataContainer" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="119" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="736"
  ItemsSource="{Binding PagedListOfPersonEmail, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColBinding}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPersonEmail, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  IsReadOnly="{Binding PersonEmailDataContainerIsReadOnly, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True"
         CanUserSort="True" Width="Auto" />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" 
         CanUserSort="True" Width="20*"
         Binding="{Binding Email, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         Header="{Binding ConverterParameter=HdrEmail, Converter={StaticResource Localization}, Source={StaticResource Localization}}"  />
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserResize="True" 
         CanUserSort="True" Width="20*"
         Binding="{Binding WebSite, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         Header="{Binding ConverterParameter=HdrWebSite, Converter={StaticResource Localization}, Source={StaticResource Localization}}"  />
  </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- more columns -->
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

I solved it by removing the first column, which is just a blank column. It displays no data, it has no bindings, it doesn't even have a header to display. Any ideas why this was causing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a DataGrid that is bound to an ItemsSource then you cannot have a sdk:DataGridTextColumn that does not have a binding. You can use the sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn instead. This column type does not require a binding.

Comment: That kind of makes sense, and it works! Thanks for the answer :)